# Display 2 array values in 1 drop down entry

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, drop-down-menu

I'm selecting two columns from my `MYSQL` table called Route and Step. Each Route has multiple Step(s) associated with it. I want to create a drop down menu that has a format similar to the following: (Route:Step). I am storing all the values from the two columns into a temporary array. How can I go about displaying the results in the format I have stated? I already have a drop down menu with just the steps, but I'd also like the route to be displayed.

```
    // Get step and route list according to flow
    $d_step_list = array();
    $query= "SELECT routes.route, steps.step ".
        "FROM steps ".
        "LEFT JOIN routes_steps_cross ON steps.serial_step = routes_steps_cross.serial_step ".
        "LEFT JOIN routes ON routes.serial_route = routes_steps_cross.serial_route ".
        "LEFT JOIN flows_routes_cross ON flows_routes_cross.serial_route = routes.serial_route ".
        "LEFT JOIN flows ON flows.serial_flow = flows_routes_cross.serial_flow ".
        "WHERE flows.serial_flow = $s_flow AND routes_steps_cross.active = 1 ".
        "ORDER BY routes.serial_route, steps.serial_route ";
        if ($show_query == 1) { print "<font size=\"-1\">".$query."</font><br>\n";}
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());         
    // First fill with blank data.
    $d_step_list[] = "";
  while ($temp_data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $d_step_list["route"] = $temp_data[0];
        $d_step_list["step"] = $temp_data[1];           
    }   





             print "<tr>\n";
            print "<th bgcolor=\"#E9E9E9\"><font size=\"-1\">Disposition Step</th>\n";              
            print "<td align=\"center\"><font size=\"-2\">\n";
            print " <br><select name=\"d_step\">\n";
            foreach($d_step_list as $step1_selected) 
            {
                if ($d_step == $step1_selected) 
                {
                    print "<option value=\"$step1_selected\" selected=\"1\">$step1_selected\n";
                } 
                else 
                {  
            print "<option value=\"$step1_selected\">$step1_selected\n";
                }
            } 
            print "</select>\n";
            print "</td>\n";                
            print "</tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the same array values each time through the loop. It should be:

```
while ($temp_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $d_step_list[] = $temp_data['route'].":".$temp_data['step'];       
}
```

Note that you need to set the element to a string, so you can compare it to `$d_step` later and so you can expand it in the string when you print it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! Sorry, but how can I go about setting the element to a string? Also, I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "compare it to $d_step later and so you can expand it in the string when you print it." Thanks in advance!

Comment: The way you wrote your original code, it looks like you were trying to make `$d_step_list` a 2-dimensional array, with each result in a row, and the route and step in different columns. But later you tried to print `$step1_selected` as if it's just a single `Route:Step` string, not an `array ([route]=>Route, [step]=>Step)`.